# Mac Mojave completely disabled my localhost

Tags: bash, macos, apache, terminal, localhost

I know people has posted similar problems, but I've not found one that matches mine.

2 days ago I finally updated to Mojave and upon trying to load my localhost in Chrome, I found that my localhost was broken. This isn't the 1st time this has happened. It's happened before with El Capitan and whatever one was before it, and this sets me off real fast as every time I update, my Mac decides to break it. And Apple themselves aren't much help at all, as they don't even know what I'm talking about.

I received this message:

```
This site can’t be reached
localhost refused to connect.
```

I then opened Terminal and ran these commands:

```
sudo apachectl start
sudo apachectl stop
sudo apachectl restart
httpd -v
```

Everything seemed to be working, but going to `localhost` still did not bring up the "It works!" message. Going to `localhost/~matthew/` still brings up the 1st mentioned message.

I've followed the instructions on [Coolest Guides On The Planet](https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/install-apache-mysql-php-on-macos-mojave-10-14/), but things don't work after the article says `The Apache version that comes in macOS Mojave is Apache/2.4.34`, I run the next bit `apachectl configtest` and I get a long message saying:

`httpd: Syntax error on line 538 of /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 8 of /private/etc/apache2/other/+php-osx.conf: Cannot load /usr/local/php5/libphp7.so into server: dlopen(/usr/local/php5/libphp7.so, 10): no suitable image found.  Did find:\n\t/usr/local/php5/libphp7.so: code signature in (/usr/local/php5/libphp7.so) not valid for use in process using Library Validation: mapped file has no cdhash, completely unsigned? Code has to be at least ad-hoc signed.\n\t/usr/local/php5/libphp7.so: stat() failed with errno=22`

I don't even know what this means. I open the files mentioned, but there doesn't appear to be anything wrong with any of them.

I start again to make sure I didn't skip anything. Same problem.

I decide to just continue. I go all the way through both the "Web Sharing / Apache" & "Webroot - System And User level" sections. At the end it says "You should only see a directory tree like structure if the folder is empty.", followed by an image. But it doesn't work.

Now in case you're wondering, no, I've never messed with any settings. I've only ever done what these guides tell me to do. I don't have any programs installed that may interfere with it.

Without this, all my PHP, database, and other things become useless. Thanks for the help.

Comment: The clue is in the error, `php5/libphp7`..

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Except that file exists. I've changed the 7 to a 5 and nothing happens.

Comment: @MatthewCampbell, I had this issue. I would attempt to go to http://localhost and I was getting the same error as you. I finally realized that  it was caused by an internet filter that was installed on my computer that was "hijacking" my localhost (Oddly enough, http:127.0.0.1 worked..) If you have a filter, try removing it